# Temporarily mounted filesystems suddenly unmount

Tags: linux, centos, mount, fstab

On a CentOS 7 machine, I've had several instances recently where filesystems mounted manually (not using an entry in fstab) suddenly get unmounted.

This always occurs when I/O is occurring on the volumes. I've seen it happen for both physical disks and ramdisks.

In all cases, the filesystems had been mounted for at least 24 hours.

Is there a difference in the way mounts are handled by Linux systems, depending on whether they're mounted manually or from fstab?

The mount commands I used were:

```
sudo mount -t tmpfs -o 10G none /ramdisk
sudo mount -t xfs /dev/sda1 /Vol1
```

Comment: Have you checked logs, dmesg etc if there is any mention about a reason?

Comment: Yes. I tried both "journalctl -p warning", and "journalctl | grep dev/sdX". Nothing there.